# Выбрать строки в первой таблице, которые отсутствуют во второй

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем доброго дня. Ребята, ищу совета.

Есть две таблицы `aaa=350` строк и `bbb=2000` строк.
Делаю выборку:

```
SELECT * FROM aaa
LEFT JOIN bbb
ON aaa.id=bbb.ids
```

**Запрос занял 0.0657 сек.**
Моя задача выбрать строки в `aaa`, которых нет в `bbb`.

Добавляю следующее **WHERE bbb.text IS NULL**:

```
SELECT * FROM aaa
LEFT JOIN bbb
ON aaa.id=bbb.ids
WHERE bbb.text IS NULL
```

В результате **Запрос занял 0.8340 сек.** Как побороть заразу? Уже перелопатил всё.

Answer (score 1):

Поменять в выборке условие на:

```
WHERE bbb.ids IS NULL
```

Нужно, чтобы выборка производилась по индексированному полю либо ключу. В данном же случае поле text, видимо, не проиндексировано, что и вызывает долгую работу запроса. Как вариант, можно повесить индекс на text, если это поле участвует в условиях каких-то других выборок.

Comment: Не помогло, хотя немного прибавило скорости

Answer (score 0):

После танцев нашел немного выход. А именно группировка. В итоге сделал следующее:

```
SELECT * FROM aaa
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM bbb GROUP BY ids) bbb
ON aaa.id=bbb.ids
WHERE bbb.text IS NULL
```

**Запрос занял 0.1293 сек.**, ну это уже лучше, чем было **0.8340 сек.**

Comment: На таком маленьком наборе данных че-то долгова-то выполняется. Приведите в вопросе примеры данных в обоих таблицах, чтобы можно точнее понять задачу.

Например, что должно вывестись в следующей ситуации:

    aaa: id    text
         1       1
         2       2
         3       3
         4       4

    bbb: ids    text
         1        1
         2     null
         4        4
         4     null
         5        5

Только id={3}? Или id={2,3}? Или id={2,3,4}? Или что-то другое?

В любом случае ваш вариант ненадежен - если ids будет повторяться, то результат непредсказуем.