# SQL. Count записей из таблицы

Tags: sql, выборка

Здравствуйте.

Помогите с запросом SQL.

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
users >> id | name
users_ignore >> userId
```

Нужно получить `COUNT(id)` из таблицы `users`, но кроме тех, которые есть в таблице `users_ignore`

Comment: Что вы пытались сделать самостоятельно ?

Comment: Берете любой из сотен ответов на подобные вопросы вроде этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/405675 и дополняете его получением count()

Answer (score 3):

По ссылке куда Вас отправили нет такого варианта

```
SELECT count([Id]])
  FROM [Users]
 where [Users].[Id] not in (SELECT [Id]  FROM [users_ignore])
```

Имхо, это Ваше решение :)

Answer (score 1):

C помощью `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_ignore ui ON ui.userId = u.id
WHERE ui.userId IS NULL
```